# Confidence Interval of the Average of a F1 Score Samples

Tags: confidence-interval, f1

I have a number of individual F1 score samples and right now I am measuring the average F1 score across this group. However, I would also like to present a confidence interval on it. Its a continuous value between 0 and 1 but which formula should i use? I know each F1 score has its own confidence interval based on Wilson's adjustment but when I take an average of a bunch of them, then what ? Thanks !

Comment: 1) Are you comfortable assuming a particular distribution? 2) Must you have an explicit formula for the confidence interval? Bootstrap is a powerful computational approach to confidence intervals. 3) Why look at the $F_1$ score? Threshold-based metrics like $F_1$ are fairly problematic, as is discussed extensively on here. [One example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312119/reduce-classification-probability-threshold)

Comment: Thanks @Dave . It would be great to have a closed form formula even if the assumptions are not entirely valid as it allows me to implement this completely within SQL. Bootstrapping is definitely most accurate but its a much more complex pipeline to implement just to get a sense of how the data is varied. Right now, im just using the usual normal distribution CI 1.96*stddev(X)/sqrt(N) to get a sense of it.

Comment: is it possible to pool together the sample data to create a single f1 score and then use wilson's adjustment for it?

Comment: Thanks @behold. Unfortunately not. We want each sample to be independent as the business goal is to measure the average across the samples.

Answer (score 1):

Given the SQL constraint, you might consider doing a comparison between bootstrap and a normal approximation. If you can show them to be close on a representative sample, you and your boss/customer might feel a lot better about using the normal approximation in a pure SQL pipeline. If the results are not close, then you know to take a different approach, such as something involving a beta distribution that is bounded between $0$ and $1$.

(You get to decide what qualifies as “close”.)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, seems like the most practical way to go. I wanted to see if the community knew of any closed form formula's just to see if i can push the bar from a stats perspective within the team. Good suggestion.